# Computer not booting from USB

Tags: windows, ubuntu, usb-flash-drive

I have an old ThinkCentre A70 with the latest Ubuntu version on it. I have downloaded the windows iso and formatted on a flash drive. I have configured bios to make it boot from usb but it just will not. It always boots to Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you turn Secure Boot OFF ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try both an EFI one and a Legacy one. Try all USB sockets. I have a ridiculous laptop where of 3 USB ports only one works!

Comment: Test the USB drive on another PC; it might be at fault. Create it using Microsoft's Media Creation Tool, for best chance of it working.

Comment: Which Windows? Windows 11 is out of the question.